# Place SQL query results into object on active userform from sql module

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have several userforms in a project, each of them has a different name for the userform but I'm using uniform names for the objects. For example, every form that needs to use a SQL query has an object called "Team" and uses the same query to pull a list of teams. Each form also has the same query in it's code with the "with" statement changed to reflect the form name. What I'd like to do is only have one instance of the query in a module called SQL or something similar. Here is an example of the type of queries I am currently using.

```
Sub GetTeams()
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Server_Name = "SDL02-VM25"
Database_Name = "PIA"
SQLStr = "select distinct[team] from dbo.[Master Staffing List]  ORDER BY [team]"
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & vbNullString
rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
With MasterStaffing.Team
.Clear
Do
.AddItem rs![Team]
rs.MoveNext
Loop Until rs.EOF
End With
rs.Close
Cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set Cn = Nothing
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Can I replace "With MasterStaffing.Team" with something that would refer to whichever form is currently active? Every form that would use this query will have an object called Team on it, so the only thing that really needs to change is the form reference.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the control you want to load as a parameter to a sub in a regular module:

E.g.:

```
LoadTeams Me.Team
```

Sub being called:

```
Sub LoadTeams(ctrl as Object)

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Server_Name = "SDL02-VM25"
    Database_Name = "PIA"
    SQLStr = "select distinct[team] from dbo.[Master Staffing List]  ORDER BY [team]"
    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & _
             Database_Name & vbNullString
    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
    With ctrl
        .Clear
        Do
            .AddItem rs![Team]
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop Until rs.EOF
    End With
    rs.Close
    Cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you want to further improve your code, factor out the database connection and querying into a separate function which accepts a SQL string and returns an open recordset.

Comment: I had considered using a universal connection but I was given to understand that it was basically always open when you do that.